# How get managed bean name from inside the backing bean?

Tags: jsf

I'm using JSF 1.1. I have the following in my `faces-config.xml` file:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>beanInstance1</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.paquete.BeanMyBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

I want get the managed bean name `beanInstance1` inside my bean. This is my bean:

```
package com.paquete;

public class BeanMyBean {
   String atribute1;

   public BeanMyBean () {
       System.out.println("managed-bean-class="+this.getClass().getName());
       System.out.println("managed-bean-name="+????????????????????????);
       // How Can I get the "beanInstance1" literal from here??
   }

   // setters and getters
}
```

I know how get the `com.paquete.BeanMyBean` literal (`this.getClass().getName()`) and the `BeanMyBean` (`this.getClass().getSimpleName()`), but I don't know how get a Managed Name (instance of Bean).

How can I get the `beanInstance1` value?

Answer (score 4):

This information is not available by the standard JSF API. Best what you can get is to walk through all the request, session and application scopes yourself the following way (code is copied from [this blog](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html#LookupTheManagedBeanNameInsideTheBackingBean)):

```
public static String lookupManagedBeanName(Object bean) {
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    Map<String, Object> requestMap = externalContext.getRequestMap();

    for (String key : requestMap.keySet()) {
        if (bean.equals(requestMap.get(key))) {
            return key;
        }
    }

    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
    for (String key : sessionMap.keySet()) {
        if (bean.equals(sessionMap.get(key))) {
            return key;
        }
    }

    Map<String, Object> applicationMap = externalContext.getApplicationMap();
    for (String key : applicationMap.keySet()) {
        if (bean.equals(applicationMap.get(key))) {
            return key;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

However, there's a big **but**, this doesn't work inside the bean's constructor simply because JSF hasn't placed it in any scope yet! You need to determine it at a later point, e.g. in an action method.

```
public void submit() {
    String name = lookupManagedBeanName(this);
    // ...
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this is a design smell. The concrete functional requirement for which you thought that this is the solution has definitely to be solved differently.